# playing h264 rtp stream in android

Tags: android, video, gstreamer, vlc

I am trying to stream h264 video from my arm development board using gstreamer and play it in my android mobile using available video player like mxplayer, vlc etc. But i am not able to play the stream in Android mobile.

Gstreamer pipeline:

> gst-launch filesrc location=./test.mp4 ! decodebin ! vpuenc !
>   rtph264pay ! udpsink host=224.0.0.1 port=3000 auto-multicast=true
>   multicast-iface=wlan0

vlc:

> rtp://@224.0.0.1:3000

But I could able to stream audio and play it without any issue as well as i could able to play the video stream in android mobile using gstreamer for android based application.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?